# What options do I have to go from Bukit Batok to the Chinese Gardens in Singapore?

Tags: public-transport, singapore

Which buses to take or which MRT to board?

Comment: There is a website for checking transportation route in Singapore, I suggest you to [go there](http://gothere.sg/maps#q:bukit%20batok%20to%20chinese%20garden) and check:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Singapore MRT Bukit Batok to Chinese Gardens]

From: [Singapore Transitlink](http://www.transitlink.com.sg/images/eguide/mrt_sys_map.htm)

Your easiest way would be to take the MRT because Chinese Gardens is just two stops away. First take the North-South 'Red' Line from Bukit Batok to Jurong East interchange, and then change over to the East-West 'Green' Line going *towards* Joo Koon. Chinese Gardens is the next stop after Jurong East, and there's a path leading from the Chinese Gardens MRT station to the actual gardens.

Comment: Check a map first though - depending on where you are in Bukit Batok it might be just as close to walk to the Chinese Gardens as it would be to walk to the Bukit Batok MRT.

Comment: @Doc: Is there a way to cross the PIE? I think that falls in the way, doesn't it?

Comment: This is Singapore, not LA. :)  Bukit Batok Road goes under the PIE, and has a footpath beside it.

Comment: I see! Given Singapore's weather, I hated walking to any place though, always preferred the (air-conditioned) MRT even for short hops.

Comment: @Doc is it really that close?

Comment: Depends where in Bukit Batok you are.  From Bukit Batok MRT to the Chinese Gardens it's ~3km (2 mile) so the train make sense - but some parts of Bukit Batok are closer.  Google Maps will show you the details.

Comment: Also Google Maps or City Mapper app will suggest bus routes. It may be more convenient.

I usually prefer bus if I am not in a hurry, as I am mostly assured a seat. The above mentioned app will give you notification when the stop is near.

Answer (score 7):

The train station, depending on which part of Bukit Batok you're living, *is quite a distance*. **Bukit Batok** is this general area that includes Bukit Gombak as well. Usually, we locals refer to the area around Bukit Gombak MRT Station, Little Guilin and near the Bukit Batok Driving Centre (BBDC in local acronym terms) as Bukit Gombak instead of Bukit Batok. Or for general reference, any road names beginning with Bukit Batok West is *generally* located within the Bukit Gombak vincinity.

Most of the trunk services (bus services that operate from one terminal to the next) run through Bukit Batok West Avenue 3 and Bukit Batok East Avenue 3 (yes, our naming of roads are not very distinctive). It is the length of road that runs from Bukit Batok Road where there is a Shell Station at the traffic junction, all the way pass Bukit Batok Central (and the Bukit Batok MRT Station) and ends at the Pan-Island Express (which we locals call by its acronym, PIE).

Along this road, you may catch bus service **157**. The bus will bring you to Jurong West, where you are to alight and walk a distance to Chinese Garden. It would be easier to take the train, but I have to say that if it's your first time in Singapore you will be able to find coffee shops around the Jurong West area where you can grab a bite after your visit to Chinese Garden.